# Objective-C equivalent of Swift "\(variable)"

Tags: objective-c, string

The question title says it all, really. In swift you use `"\()"` for string interpolation of a variable. How does one do it with Objective-C?

Comment: `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent. The closest you will get is using a string format.

```
NSString *text = @"Tomiris";
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My name is %@", text];
```

Swift supports this as well:

```
let text = "Tomiris"
let someString = String(format: "My name is %@", text)
```

Of course when you use a format string like this (in either language), the biggest issue is that you need to use the correct format specifier for each type of variable. Use `%@` for object pointers. Use `%d` for integer types, etc. It's all documented.

Comment: One thing to add to this is that Clang has a `-Wformat` option that will check your format strings to make sure the types are correct. I'd make sure you have that enabled, because you can really shoot yourself in the foot if you let these get mismatched.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Good point. Xcode will give you warnings as well.

Comment: Different syntax, but similar result. I'd say this *is* the equivalent of Swift's string interpolation.

Comment: @Caleb Since both languages support string formats and only Swift supports its string interpolation syntax, I would say that Objective-C does not have any equivalent to string interpolation.

Comment: I wonder how to you apply to an array that calls for a lot of "\()" For example, I like to be able to use change the value of "hotel" else where. Can this be done with obj-c? 
var roomNumberArray = ["\\(hotel)01", "\\(hotel)02", "\\(hotel)03", "\\(hotel)04", "\\(hotel)05", "\\(hotel)06", "\\(hotel)07", "\\(hotel)08", "\\(hotel)09", "\\(hotel)10"]

Comment: @Tomiris You would never do that in Swift. You would use `map` to generate that array: `let roomNumberArray = (1...10).map { String(format: "%@%02d", hotel, $0) }`.

Comment: @rmaddy that's cool code - definitely something worth putting into my daily small coding repertoire. So how can one achieve the same result in Obj-C?

Comment: @Tomiris That's the subject of a whole new question. Your original question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

@rmaddy's Answer is the gist of it. I just wanted to follow up on his comment that "*It's all documented*". Well, these symbols like `%@` and `%d` are called **String Format Specifiers** the documentation can be found at the following links.

Formatting String Objects
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

String Format Specifiers
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Just telling us noobs "It's all documented" isn't very helpful because often (if you're like me) you googled to find this stackoverflow post at the top of the SEO. And taking the link in hopes of finding the original documentation!